# What criteria charactarize the minimum rate for transferring information without loss?

Tags: information-theory, compression

My question in other words is: what is the condition to do data compression and later decompress the data without any loss ?

Comment: are you looking for the kolmogorov complexity?

Comment: @shimao No, it's a question related to the Entropy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimum rate for transferring information without loss is that:

Data flow should not be less than the entropy of the source.

Entropy: $E=-\sum p(x_{i}) * log_{2}(p(x_{i}))$